# Make iframe size of browser

Tags: iframe

How can i make an iframe the absolute size of a web browser? I'm playing around with this (http://liquor.com/askmen-jardiniere/) yet whatever I do in Firebug it's showing scrollers on the right and bottom. I've set the width/height to 100% but that doesn't work, auto width/height won't work, even setting scroller="no" or scrolling="no" isn't working.

Seeking a guru to lend a hand if possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[EDIT]**
Aha I found the Answer (at least it seems like it):

```
<html> 
 <head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
 </head>
 <body style="paddin:0px;margin:0px;"> 
  <iframe src="http://liquor.com/askmen-jardiniere/" scrolling="no" style="width:100%;height:100%;border:none;"/>
 </body>
</html>
```

This is because browsers have default stylesheets and the put paddings for the Body tag.

Comment: ah you are a genius. i removed the scrolling option as it obviously turned the right scroller off so i couldn't see the full page. it seemed to remove the bottom scroller so this seems to be fixed! why 99% on height instead of 100%?

Comment: oh, that was a mistake. See the edited code. I put the paddings of the Body to 0.

Comment: seems it crashes in Safari. looks horrible in Safari, any idea how to get to this work in all browsers?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have Safari installed. I'll try to get one and see what the problem is.

Comment: I checked it with Safari 5. No problem. could you explain what the problem is and with what version?